# Получить атрибут внешней сборки (c#)

Tags: c#, атрибуты, assembly

Есть два файла: библиотека и сама программа.
В библиотеке находится информация в виде настраиваемого атрибута M (содержится в ещё одной библиотеке amlib):

```
using amlib;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly : M("css", version = 0.1)]
```

Необходимо получить значение свойства этого атрибута из основной программы (т.е. из другой сборки).

Вот класс самого настраиваемого атрибута:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace amlib
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class M : System.Attribute
    {
        private string name;
        public double version;

        public M(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            version = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем сложность то? `amlib.М` подключив через ссылки эту библиотеку

Comment: Это как это? во время выполнения? Библиотеки с классом наследуемых от атрибут и использующиеся в асембле конечно должны быть слинкованы статически. По другому не выйдет, это у вас получается базовый тип.

Comment: Проблема в том, что библиотека подключается во время выполнения программы. Я пытался сделать что-то вроде: var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(путь до библиотеки);  var attrType = asm.GetType("M"); var attrObj = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(asm, attrType); double b = (double) attrType.GetProperty("version").GetValue(attrObj, null); Но asm.GetType("M") возвращает null

Comment: А где вы это пытаетесь делать? Директивы асембле по сути сами являются "макросами/атрибутами", их собирают в первую очередь и все зависимости должны быть разрешены к этому моменту.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чём вы говорите. Возможно, я неправильно выразился. Моя идея в целом аналогична https://forum.antichat.ru/threads/282752/

Comment: Решение несколько проще, сделайте ещё одну длл, положите в нее класс атрибута и линкуйте со всеми библиотеками где оно используется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, которое мне было нужно:

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(путь до библиотеки, из которой извлекается атрибут);
var version = (double)asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(amlib.M), false).Cast<amlib.M>().First().version;
Console.WriteLine(version);
```